# Using directory names containing spaces in Bash

Tags: bash, loops, directory

I'm trying to do some operations with directories that containing spaces in their names via for loop. This is what I'm using;

```
    dirs=$(ls -d1 */ | cut -f1 -d'/')

for dir in $dirs
    do 
        echo "${dir}"
        mkdir -p $outputdir/"${dir}"
        cd "${dir}"
        for file in *.$inputformat
```

But cannot operate directories with spaces in their names. What can  I do else?

Comment: Put a shebang on your code and paste it at https://shellcheck.net

Comment: Although the first thing you need to do is quote your variables, and avoid using `ls` is scripts.

Comment: this is whole code: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/XG9gpGsJGK/

Comment: @Jetchisel what should I use else?

Comment: [Don't parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), and don't expect word-splitting on unquoted variables (e.g. `for dir in $dirs`) to do anything sane. Use shell wildcards (like `for dir in */`) and `find ... -print0`. See [BashFAQ #20: How can I find and safely handle file names containing newlines, spaces or both?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020)

Answer (score 0):

> What can I do else?

Just iterate over the pattern. Your script may look like this:

```
for dir in */; do         # !!
     if [[ ! -e "$dir" ]]; then break; fi   # or use shopt -s nullglob
     echo "$dir"
     mkdir -p "$outputdir/${dir}"
     cd "${dir}"
     for file in *."$inputformat"; do
           echo "$file!"
     done
     cd -
done
```

It's good to use `shopt -s nullglob` to handle the no matches casem.